# If the number of rows in a group exceeds X number of observations, randomly sample X number of rows

Tags: r, random, subset

I need to reduce the number of rows in a data set. To do this my strategy is to the number of rows in a group exceeds X number of observations, randomly sample `X` number of rows from each group if the number of rows in a group exceeds `X` rows.

Assume the following data set:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10

df <- data.frame(id = c(1:n),
                 group = sample(1:3, n, replace = T))

> df
   id group
1   1     3
2   2     3
3   3     3
4   4     2
5   5     3
6   6     2
7   7     2
8   8     2
9   9     3
10 10     1
```

where `X == 2`. Let's count the number of rows in each group.

```
> table(df$group)

1 2 3 
1 4 5
```

This means that in the end result, I want 1 observation in groups one, and 2 in groups 2 and 3. The row that is kept in groups 2 and 3 should be randomly selected. This would reduce the data's size from 10 rows to 5.

How do I do this in an efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to group by group column and create a condition in `slice` to check if the number of rows (`n()`) is greater than 'X', sample the sequence of rows (`row_number()`) with `X` or else return `row_number()` (or sample in case `X` is different value

```
library(dplyr)
X <- 2
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice(if(n() >= X) sample(row_number(), X, replace = FALSE) else 
     sample(row_number())) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
     id group
  <int> <int>
1    10     1
2     8     2
3     4     2
4     1     3
5     9     3
```

Comment: `sample(row_number(), replace = FALSE)[seq_len(X)]` could also be a possibility.

Comment: Are there any ways to do this using ```data.table```
?

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding an alternative method using `data.table` that seems to work. Good to have alternatives.

```
library(data.table)

X <- 2

setkey(df, "id") 

df[
  df[,
     if(.N >= X)
       .I[sample(.N, X, replace = FALSE)]
     else
       .I[sample(.N, replace = FALSE)], 
     by = group
  ]$V1
]
```

Which leads to this outcome.

```
   id group
1:  5     3
2:  2     3
3:  6     2
4:  4     2
5: 10     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably we can use `pmin` when we randomly `sample` rows by groups

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    slice(sample(n(), pmin(n(), 2))) %>%
    ungroup()
```

and below is an `data.table` equivalent

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[sample(.N, pmin(.N, X))], group]
```